# d3v4 update creates duplicate element

Tags: d3.js

I have rewritten most of my d3 code to v4, but the new update pattern is throwing me off. The example below is for a force diagram. A duplicate circle is created within the first container upon every update. The data in my example does not actually change, but it's irrelevant. If I use new data, the same issue (a duplicate circle) occurs.

```
var w = 800,
    h = 500;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

var dataset = {};

function setData() {
    dataset.nodes = [{
        value: 200
    }, {
        value: 100
    }, {
        value: 50
    }];
}
setData();

var rScale = d3.scaleSqrt()
    .range([0, 100])
    .domain([0, d3.max(dataset.nodes.map(function(d) {
        return d.value;
    }))]);

var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + w / 2 + "," + h / 2 + ")")
    .selectAll(".node");

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(dataset.nodes)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1600))
    .force("x", d3.forceX())
    .force("y", d3.forceY())
    .alphaDecay(.05)
    .on("tick", ticked);

function ticked() {
    node.selectAll("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });
}

function restart() {
    // Apply the general update pattern to the nodes.
    node = node.data(dataset.nodes, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
    node.exit().remove();
    node = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .merge(node);
    node.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return rScale(d.value);
        });

    // Update and restart the simulation.
    simulation.nodes(dataset.nodes);
    simulation.alpha(1).restart();
}
restart();

function update() {
    setData();
    restart();
}

d3.select("#update").on("click", update);
```

If you click the Update button in this codepen (https://codepen.io/cplindem/pen/wpQbQe), you will see all three circles animate as the simulation restarts, but behind the largest circle, there is another, identical circle that does not animate. You can also see the new circle appear in the html if you inspect it.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first problem seems to be that you are keying the data on an 'id' field, but your data doesn't have any ids, so that needs changed or you just keep adding new groups:

```
function setData() {
    dataset.nodes = [{
        value: 200,
      id: "A"
    }, {
        value: 100,
      id: "B"
    }, {
        value: 50,
      id: "C"
    }];
    console.log("dataset", dataset);
}
```

The second problem is you merge the new and updated selection and then append new circles to all of them, even the existing ones (so you have multiple circles per group on pressing update). I got it to work by doing this: make the new nodes, merge with existing selection, add circles to just the new nodes, update the circles in all the nodes:

```
   node.exit().remove();
   var newNodes = node.enter().append("g");
   node = newNodes
        .attr("class", "node")
        .merge(node);

   newNodes.append("circle");

   node.select("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) {
            return rScale(d.value);
        });
```

Whether that 2nd bit is optimal I don't know, I'm still more anchored in v3 myself...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WdLexR

Comment: Thank you - for some reason I thought v4 automatically created the id, but it appears only index is available by default.